# Why isn't my scheduled task triggered reliably?

Tags: scheduled-task, windows-server-2016

It's 19:01 now. This is what the Scheduled Tasks window on my Windows Server 2016 shows:

[image: unreliable task]

As you can see, the highlighted task is:

- triggered to run at xx:15 every hour,
- is scheduled to run again at 19:15 and
- last ran at 16:15.

When I checked about an hour ago, the "Next Run Time" was "08.02.2017 18:15:00". However, as you can see in the screen shot, it did not run, and the task history does not tell me why.

For completeness, the remaining settings of the task are:

- *General* tab: SYSTEM account, *"run with highest privileges"*.
- *Conditions* tab: none checked.
- *Settings* tab: *"Allow task to be run on demand"*, *"Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days"* and *"If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop"* are checked. If the task is already running, *"Do not start a new instance"* is selected.

**What steps can I take to find out *why* the task does not start sometimes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some recent changes on task scheduler behaviour (windows 10, windows server 2016). Your task will probably start today at 14:15, and then it will repeat every hour for 1 day. But, if you change something and save the task, or if the operative system restarts, the task will only run after it reaches a trigger point, which will be the next 14:15 hour schedule.

I think this is an important change that I have not seen documented by Microsoft, and in my opinion it should be. It changes a behaviour that was standard for many years...

Carlos Maia

Comment: I did a bit more research and, apparently, at has always been that way: See the first comment [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4250516/87698)).